# Moving Specific Files in Specific Directory

Tags: shell-script, backup, for

I've some files in directory */app/me/all_off* which filename like below :

- access_log
- alarm-batch
- alarm-service-root
- db_wrapper_access_log
- db_wrapper_api_service
- moqueue-job
- mt_push_api_service
- mtqueue-job
- nbp_request_handler
- profile_api_service
- promo_api_service
- queue-service-root

then, it files formatted with extention **.log** and they generated everyday with formatted : xxxx.log.20190101

therefore, I want to archive and move all of that files **(files with last generated one day before now)** into */app/me/all_off/backup/* Everyday at 12AM. **But I want to backup that files in specific directory** (as based on their name) like example :

- > /app/me/all_off/backup/access_log/access_log.log.2019010

**Is there any problem-solving for my case ?**

I'm using Shellscript for Archive and Move that file, but it just only moved into */app/me/all_off/backup/* . Below for my Shellscript :

> (#!/bin/bash ----> "(" just remarks
>
> date1=`date -d "yesterday" +%Y%m%d`
>
> date2=`date -d "yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d`
>
> logPathMove=$logPath"backup/"
>
> logPath='/app/me/all_off/'
>
> all=`ls -ltrh *log* *log | awk -F ' ' '{print$9}' | awk -F '.' '{print$1}' | sort | uniq -c | awk -F ' ' '{print$2}'`
>
> cd ${logPath}
>
> gzip -9 *.${date1}
>
> gzip -9 *.${date1}.log --------> another format of filename
>
> gzip -9 *log.${date2}.log --------> another format of filename
>
> cd {logPath}
>
> for i in *.gz; do mv ${i} ${logPathMove}; done

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit hard to exactly make out what you want to do.
However here is a general trick to help debug shell scripts: Put this line at the start of your script:

```
set -x
```

So if the script is:

```
b=1
echo a $b
```

Running it produces

```
a 1
$
```

Whereas if you make it

```
set -x
b=1
echo a $b
```

it produces

```
+ b=1
+ echo a 1
a 1
$
```

In other words you'll see what commands are being executed along with the variable substitutions along with the output.